# Menu icons in Xamarin randomly change

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have menu in my Xamarin app like this:

[image]

And the icons should be like this all the time. However, for some reason when navigating through the app, the icons shuffle themselves, so for example "Mapa" has e-shop icon and the rest stays OK.

I setup my menu this way:

```
        menuItemsLogged = new List<HomeMenuItem>
        {
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Account, Title="Můj účet", Image =  "account.png" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Home, Title="Novinky", Image =  "home.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.List, Title="Seznam magnetek", Image =  "list.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Collection, Title="Moje magnetky", Image =  "collection.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Bonus, Title="Bonusové magnetky", Image =  "bonus.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.ShopList, Title="Seznam prodejních míst", Image =  "location.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Map, Title="Mapa", Image =  "map.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Shop, Title="E-shop", Image =  "eshop.png"},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Contact, Title="Kontakt", Image =  "contact.png"}
        };
        ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItemsLogged;
        ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItemsLogged[1];
        ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;
            await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
        };
```

This is the only place in the whole app that "touches" the icons in any way.

How can this even be happening and where do I look for fix?
I thought about some function that would reset the icons in background let's say every time user opens menu or something, but maybe the fix is far simpler.

Comment: Do you use MasterDetailPage? If not, suggesting you can use MasterDetailPage.

Comment: If you use Xamarin.Forms 5.0 above, it is renamed to [Xamarin.Forms FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage)